# How can we pull images from a website and display in our app using iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

How can we pull images from a website and display in our app using iphone sdk?

Also, how can we embed audio in our iPhone App using iPhone SDK?

Can you please refer to any tutorial / videos related to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @PeteRossi said, you can use this code:

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlOfImage];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
```

However, I would look into using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for downloading things from the web. ASIHTTPRequest contains powerful classes for downloading things asynchronously so that your app won't have to wait for that image to download before it continues.

Comment: I tried using the above code but it positions the images only at the top left corner of the screen no matter what the frame of the imageview is. What should be done?

Comment: You should create a `frame` using `CGREctMake` and set the frame property of your UIImageview.

Answer (score 0):

Pulling an image from a website:

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlOfImage];  
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
```

As for your second question, it depends on what you are trying to do.  Here is an overview:

http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/audio-and-video.html